# d3heatmap in R for 1D array

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to represent percentile values with different colors . Example :

[image]

my data is something like this :

```
[71.42857142857143,46.42857142857143,32.142857142857146,67.85714285714286,32.142857142857146, 80.5874840357599,17.857142857142858]
```

when I do :

```
d3heatmap(df, scale = "row", dendrogram = c("none"))
```

I get the error : x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Is there some other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is your `df` an array / matrix? I.e. does `dim(df)` return 2 values? I suspect it has to be for this to work properly

Comment: df is just an array of 7 values . My question was whether there is some alternative to solve this since d3heatmap requires data in matrix form with at least 2 rows